# Automatically run script on workdays using app script in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I currently have a function that basically copies values from one tab to another using certain conditions in which i execute daily via menu added in google sheets, how can i create a script that runs on workdays (monday to friday) at 6AM GTM-3 time and calls function copyData () to be executed?
I have this code not working:

```
function createTriggers() { 
var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY]; 
 for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) { 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(copyData).timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i]) .atHour(6).create(); 
 } 
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
function myFunction(){
  if (testDate()==true) {copyData()}
}
function testDate(){
  var d = new Date();
  // not on sunday and saturday 
  if (d.getDay()!=0 && d.getDay()!=6) {return true} else {return false}
}
```

Put a daily trigger myFunction

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(6)
      .create();
}
```

Comment: I agree with Mike and that is how I have my daily triggers set, have the trigger fire every day and add code to decide whether it should run or not.

Comment: for some reason it is not working, i have inserted the code with a call to the function but the function did not execute at the hour that was set, can i specify the GMT to the time?

Comment: what is the gap? a few minutes or a few hours? you may probably to change your settings in the script editor. What is your locartion? Click on the gearbow at the left hand side of your script editor, then activate the third checkbox, go back to the scripts and check the value of timezone in appsscript.json. Change as needed.

Comment: @Jay Navarro, did you fix now the issue?

Comment: is does not run at all, the function only runs when i manually run it, but with your code it should run automatically, right? do i need to set something in triggers? because i only inserted that as an additional script in my app script file and it did not run at all, even after more than a day has passed :/
i also checked the timezone and it is correct with my location
{
  "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
 ..
}
PS: I have inserted the code after the onOpen(){} and after the onEdit(e){} function , at the end of them all i have inserted the function and did not run even once on its own

Comment: I don't know what is copydata() for you. It works well on my side with `if (testDate() == true) {SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2').getRange('A1').setValue(new Date())}` I verified the trigger that is weell configured each days at about 6 hours.